# Discord py - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, attributeerror

I have been searching the stackoverflow questions for hours now and cant seem to figure out where I am going wrong.  I am attempting to make discord bot that removes the 'Newbie' role after the user obtains 'verified' role.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if len(before.roles) < len(after.roles):
        newRole = next(role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles)
        member = after.name
        currentRoles = after.roles

        if newRole.name == "verified":
            removeRole = discord.utils.get(currentRoles, name="Newbie")
            await member.remove_roles(removeRole)
```

I have tried alot of different combanations and also searched the [discordpy](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=remove_role#discord.Member.remove_roles) but cant not seem to get the syntax.

`removeRole = <id>`

`removeRole = (id=<id>)`

`remove_role = get(after.roles, name="Newbie")`

`await member.remove_roles(<id>)`

Here is the full error

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "security.py", line 117, in on_member_update
    await member.remove_roles(removeRole)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
The issue in your code is `member` is defined as a string, not an actual [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) object hence, no attribute as `remove_roles`. The [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event gives you a Member object already. So, you can define `member` as `member = after` and call `remove_roles` on the Member object now.
`member.remove_roles(removeRole)`

Answer (score 0):

what I would do is:

```
user = self.client.get_user(after.id)
```

This way a user is actually an object, not a name.

if this doesn't work try:

```
user = self.client.get_user(after.id)
if user is None:
     user = await self.client.fetch_user(after.id)
```